# Toolbar back arrow icon not align with Title

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm trying to align back arrow icon  of toolbar with toolbar title but didn't find any useful method do this,

By default if you will set subtitle and title text, then back arrow icon will  vertical align e.g set in middle by default,

I know I can do it by giving custom layout in toolbar , but I want to know is there any default method or behaviour to this ?

[image]

```
 /**
     * For setting up actionbar/Toolbar
     */
    private void  setUpToolbar(){

        // Set a toolbar to replace the action bar.
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //Enabling up back-up arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        //Callback of up button pressed
        //mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //What to do on back clicked
            }
        });

        //setting up toolbar text
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getToolbarTitle());
        //mToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(getToolbarSubTitle());
        //mToolbar.setSubtitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorPrimary));

        //set back arrow icon in middle
        View navButtonView = getNavButtonView(mToolbar);

        if(navButtonView != null) {
            Toolbar.LayoutParams lp = (Toolbar.LayoutParams) navButtonView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            navButtonView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Toolbar` class doesn't directly expose its child `View`s or their properties, but you can get a reference to that `View` using reflection.

```
private View getNavButtonView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    try {
        Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
        Field navButtonField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView");
        navButtonField.setAccessible(true);
        View navButtonView = (View) navButtonField.get(toolbar);

        return navButtonView;
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

After the `View` has been created, you can get a reference to it, and adjust its `LayoutParams` as desired.

```
View navButtonView = getNavButtonView(toolbar);

if(navButtonView != null) {
    Toolbar.LayoutParams lp = (Toolbar.LayoutParams) navButtonView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    navButtonView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But still back arrow remain in center :(

Comment: Could you post more info about your setup? Like your layout and the `Toolbar` initialization. I'll see if I can get it working for your situation. Also, which Android version you're running under.

Comment: Hmm, your code works for me. Are you doing anything with the `Toolbar` or the support `ActionBar` after you call `setUpToolbar()`? Like creating an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`? Also, which Android version are you running?

Comment: No, I didnt do anything with toolbar, and also i do not using ActionBarDrawerTogglem, I using lollipop rigth now but this should work for all flavor

Comment: No, I didnt do anything with toolbar, and also i do not using ActionBarDrawerTogglem, I using lollipop rigth now but this should work for all flavor

Comment: Check to see if it's entering the `if` block. That is, check if `navButtonView` is null. The only thing I can think of at moment is that the `Toolbar` class has changed. I'll pull the latest source code, and give it a look, when I get a minute a little later.

Comment: Well, I dunno. There's nothing I can see in the latest source that is any different, as far as laying out the child `View`s. Also, in my tests, it aligns to the top by default, as it always has for me. You might try setting the gravity in `onPostCreate()` instead. Or putting it in a `Runnable`, and call `post()` with that on the `Toolbar` at the end of `setUpToolbar()`. If you want to post your layout and the complete `onCreate()` method, I'll have a look, but I can't think of anything that would override the layout parameters. Are you testing on a device, or an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not get direct option for setting position you can also have another option, this option is for different customization.
For customizing toolbar buttons, you should make your custom toolbar. I mean instead of using

```html
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

You can add your own button in toolbar and align the position as you want.

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
 
   <Button
      android:id="@+id/back_button"
      ....
      />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      ....
      />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```